# How to identify if an Office 365 group has guests via MS graph API or via any other method?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365api, azure-ad-graph-api

I am setting up housekeeping process for guests accounts in Azure AD and for that purpose I want to know which Office 365 groups have Guests as members. How can I identify those groups which are externally shared via MS Graph API? Is there any property available?

Answer (score 0):

You could look with reportRoot: getOffice365GroupsActivityDetail

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/reportroot-getoffice365groupsactivitydetail?view=graph-rest-1.0

It seems this endpoint can give you "External Member Count" with the "Group Display Name"

Comment: thanks this is really a good input but I think this will be too heavy operation if for any reason i have to look for guests in a group on daily basis. So no other way to go? Otherwise I have to get all members and then filter out at client side (filter by user id)